# Turing Machine Implementation in C

Tags: c, turing-machines

I'm studying Turing machines for my course in formal languages ​​theory, the professor recommended a run on the following [algorithm](http://code.zhoubot.com/archives/52) to see in detail the logic behind of a "TM", but doesn't work, when trying to compile tells me the following error.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Melkhiah.EQUIPO01\Mis documentos\Downloads\Tarea3 Discretas\TM.c||In function `Tape* insert_tape(Tape*, Direction, char)':|
C:\Documents and Settings\Melkhiah.EQUIPO01\Mis documentos\Downloads\Tarea3 Discretas\TM.c|44|error: invalid conversion from `void*' to `Tape*'|
C:\Documents and Settings\Melkhiah.EQUIPO01\Mis documentos\Downloads\Tarea3 Discretas\TM.c||In function `Tape* create_tape(char*)':|
C:\Documents and Settings\Melkhiah.EQUIPO01\Mis documentos\Downloads\Tarea3 Discretas\TM.c|68|error: invalid conversion from `void*' to `Tape*'|
C:\Documents and Settings\Melkhiah.EQUIPO01\Mis documentos\Downloads\Tarea3 Discretas\TM.c||In function `Transition* get_transition(char*)':|
C:\Documents and Settings\Melkhiah.EQUIPO01\Mis documentos\Downloads\Tarea3 Discretas\TM.c|80|error: invalid conversion from `void*' to `Transition*'|
C:\Documents and Settings\Melkhiah.EQUIPO01\Mis documentos\Downloads\Tarea3 Discretas\TM.c||In function `List* insert_list(List*, char*)':|
C:\Documents and Settings\Melkhiah.EQUIPO01\Mis documentos\Downloads\Tarea3 Discretas\TM.c|93|error: invalid conversion from `void*' to `List*'|
C:\Documents and Settings\Melkhiah.EQUIPO01\Mis documentos\Downloads\Tarea3 Discretas\TM.c||In function `List* insert_list_transition(List*, Transition*)':|
C:\Documents and Settings\Melkhiah.EQUIPO01\Mis documentos\Downloads\Tarea3 Discretas\TM.c|105|error: invalid conversion from `void*' to `List*'|
C:\Documents and Settings\Melkhiah.EQUIPO01\Mis documentos\Downloads\Tarea3 Discretas\TM.c||In function `TM* createTM(char*)':|
C:\Documents and Settings\Melkhiah.EQUIPO01\Mis documentos\Downloads\Tarea3 Discretas\TM.c|166|error: invalid conversion from `void*' to `TM*'|
C:\Documents and Settings\Melkhiah.EQUIPO01\Mis documentos\Downloads\Tarea3 Discretas\TM.c|167|error: invalid conversion from `void*' to `List*'|
||=== Build finished: 7 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

here's the code:

```
/* This C file implements a Non-determinitic Pushdown Automata
 * author: Kevin Zhou
 * Computer Science and Electronics
 * University of Bristol
 * Date: 21st April 2010
 */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct tapes {
    struct tapes *left;
    struct tapes *right;
    char content;
} Tape;

typedef enum { LEFT,RIGHT } Direction;

typedef struct transition {
    char current_state;
    char tape_symbol;
    char new_state;
    char new_tape_symbol;
    Direction dir;
} Transition;

typedef struct list {
    Transition *content;
    struct list *next;
} List;

typedef struct tm {
    char *input_alpha;
    char *input;
    char *tape_alpha;
    char start;
    char accept;
    char reject;
    List *transition;
} TM;

Tape *insert_tape(Tape *t, Direction dir, char c) {
    Tape *head = t;
    Tape *new1 = calloc(1,sizeof(Tape));;
    new1 -> content = c;
    if(dir == LEFT) {
        while(t->left != NULL) {
            t = t->left;
        }
        new1->right = t;
        new1->left = NULL;
        t->left = new1;
        return new1;
    }
    if(dir == RIGHT) {
        while(t->right != NULL) {
            t = t->right;
        }
        new1->left = t;
        new1->right = NULL;
        t->right = new1;
    }
    return head;
}

Tape *create_tape(char *input) {
    int i=1;
    Tape *t = calloc(1,sizeof(Tape));
    t->content = input[0];
    while(1) {
        if(input[i] == '\0') break;
        t = insert_tape(t,RIGHT,input[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return t;
}

/* turn the input string into Transition fields */
Transition *get_transition(char *s) {
    Transition *t = calloc(1,sizeof(Transition));
    Direction dir;
    t->current_state = s[0];
    t->tape_symbol = s[1];
    t->new_state = s[2];
    t->new_tape_symbol = s[3];
    dir = (s[4]=='R')? RIGHT:LEFT;
    t->dir = dir;
    return t;
}

/* turn the string into transitions and add into list */
List *insert_list( List *l, char *elem ) {
    List *t = calloc(1,sizeof(List));
    List *head = l;
    while(l->next!=NULL)
        l = l->next;
    t->content = get_transition(elem);
    t->next = NULL;
    l->next = t;
    return head;
}

/* insert a transition into a list */
List *insert_list_transition( List *l, Transition *tr) {
    List *t = calloc(1,sizeof(List));
    List *head = l;
    while(l->next!=NULL)
        l = l->next;
    t->content = tr;
    t->next = NULL;
    l->next = t;
    return head;
}

void print_tape( Tape *t,char blank) {
    char c;
    while(1) {
        if(t->content != blank) break;
        t= t->right;
    }
    while(1) {
        if(t==NULL) break;
        c = t->content;
        if(t->content != blank)
            putchar(c);
        t= t->right;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

void print_transition (Transition *t) {
    char s1[] = "Left";
    char s2[] = "Right";
    if(t==NULL) {
        printf("NULL Transfer");
        return;
    }
    printf("current:%c tape:%c new state:%c new tape:%c direction %s\n",t->current_state,t->tape_symbol,t->new_state,t->new_tape_symbol,(t->dir == LEFT)?s1:s2);
}

/*test if the char c is in the string s */
int contains ( char c, char *s ) {
    int i=0;
    while(1) {
        if(c== s[i]) return 1;
        if(s[i] == '\0') return 0;
        i++;
    }
}

/* test if the input is a valid input */
int is_valid_input( char *input_alpha, char *input ) {
    int i=0;
    char c;
    while(1) {
        c = input[i];
        if(c == '\0') break;
        if(!contains(c,input_alpha)) return 0;
        i++;
    }
    return 1;
}

TM *createTM (char *input) {

    TM *m = calloc(1,sizeof(TM));
    List *tr = calloc(1,sizeof(List));
    char *buffer;
    /*read input alphabet of PDA*/
    buffer = strtok(input,":");
    if(buffer == NULL) {
        printf("Error in reading input alphabet!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    m->input_alpha = buffer;

    /*read tape alphabet*/
    buffer = strtok(NULL,":");

    if(buffer == NULL) {
        printf("Error in reading tape alphabet!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    m->tape_alpha = buffer;

    /*read input sequence*/
    buffer = strtok(NULL,":");
    if(buffer == NULL) {
        printf("Error in reading input sequence!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(!is_valid_input(m->input_alpha,buffer)) {
        printf("Error! Input contains some invalid characters that don't match the input alphabet!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    m->input = buffer;
    buffer = strtok(NULL,":");
    m->start = buffer[0];
    buffer = strtok(NULL,":");
    m->accept = buffer[0];
    buffer = strtok(NULL,":");
    m->reject = buffer[0];

    /*read tape transition*/
    while(1) {
        buffer = strtok(NULL,":");
        if(buffer == NULL) break;
        tr = insert_list(tr,buffer);
    }

    m->transition = tr->next;
    return m;
}

Transition *find_transition(List * list,char state, char tape_symbol) {
    Transition *t;
    while(1) {
        if(list==NULL) return NULL;
        t = list -> content;
        if(t->current_state == state && t->tape_symbol == tape_symbol)
            return t;
        list = list->next;
    }
}

Tape *move(Tape *t,Direction dir, char blank) {
    if(dir == LEFT) {
        if(t->left==NULL) {
            t = insert_tape(t,LEFT,blank);
        }
        return t->left;
    }
    if(dir == RIGHT) {
        if(t->right==NULL) {
            t = insert_tape(t,RIGHT,blank);
        }
        return t->right;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void simulate( TM *m ) {
    /* first symbol in input symbol used to represent the blank symbol */
    const char blank = m->tape_alpha[0];
    char current_state = m->start;
    Tape *tape = create_tape(m->input);
    Tape *current_tape = tape;
    char current_tape_symbol;
    Transition *current_transition;
    while(1) {
        if(current_state == m->accept) {
            printf("Accept\n");
            print_tape(tape,blank);
            break;
        }
        if(current_state == m->reject) {
            printf("Reject\n");
            print_tape(tape,blank);
            break;
        }
        current_tape_symbol = (current_tape==NULL||current_tape ->content == '\0')?blank:current_tape->content;
        current_transition = find_transition(m->transition,current_state,current_tape_symbol);
        current_state = current_transition -> new_state;
        current_tape -> content = current_transition -> new_tape_symbol;
        current_tape = move( current_tape, current_transition ->dir, blank);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char s[300];
    TM *p;
    scanf("%s",s);
    p = createTM(s);
    simulate(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is this program not work?

Comment: You've tagged this C, and the comment says "This C file," but the file is `.cpp`, which usually means C++, and the first error is complaining about `new`, which sounds like a C++ problem. Did you read the errors? They all have line numbers. Go to each line that produces an error, look at it and see if you can see anything wrong. Then, simplify this down to the simplest compilable code that produces any error (or errors) you can't solve, and give us that. Don't dump your entire program on us and say "Fix it" without at least showing you've put in some effort.

Comment: @Chris Luts i changed the extension to .c but is not working, even change the new by new1, but tells me the following error: C:\Documents and Settings\Melkhiah.EQUIPO01\Mis documentos\Downloads\Tarea3 Discretas\TM.c|44|error: invalid conversion from `void*' to `Tape*'|

Comment: @Melkhiah66: You're still using a C++ compiler. Tom's answer below was only half-right - it also depends on your compiler options and how you call it.

Comment: @Melkhiah88: what command are you (or the makefile/build script) using to invoke the compiler?

Comment: how are you supposed to take input string, i mean does ur code work on language like eg aabb and work on binary transitions like 1011011011 ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The program provided is in C, however, you're compiling with a C++ compiler.

Compile again using C, and you should be ok.

Answer (score 2):

The code is being treated as C++ because the file extension is .cpp. Change it to .c and it should work. This is much easier (and less likely to cause problems) then starting to modify the source code to make it C++ compatible.

**Edit:** I assumed the compiler being used was `gcc` or `cl`, which **do** detect the language based on the file extension. Since that is not the case, you'll have to tell us what compiler (and options) you are using.

**Edit 2:** In order to get it to work with a C++ compiler, you'll have to rename `new` to `new1`  like @whitelionV suggested and cast all the `calloc()` return values to the appropriate types like this:

```
44     Tape *new1 = (Tape*)calloc(1,sizeof(Tape));;
68     Tape *t = (Tape *)calloc(1,sizeof(Tape));
80     Transition *t = (Transition *)calloc(1,sizeof(Transition));
93     List *t = (List *)calloc(1,sizeof(List));
105    List *t = (List *)calloc(1,sizeof(List));
166    TM *m = (TM *)calloc(1,sizeof(TM));
167    List *tr = (List *)calloc(1,sizeof(List));
```

Comment: @MichaelBurr The question has been changed (see the edits - originally the file was turing_machine.cpp). Both gcc and cl use the file extension to determine whether it's C or C++.

Comment: @tom: gcc does NOT use the file extension to determine whether it's C or C++.  gcc is a C compiler. g++ is a C++ compiler, both of which are part of the Gnu Compiler Collection (GCC).

Comment: I tested this, and gcc definitely doesn't treat a.c and a.cpp the same. From http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_54.html: "... gcc will actually compile C++ source code when it detects a C++ file extension, but cannot then link the resulting object files."

Comment: @Arafangion: GCC is not just a C compiler, GCC can compile C and C++, and a lot more with specific front ends; hence the 'Compiler Collection'

Comment: @whitelionV: Yes... I believe I mentioned that.  The Gnu Compiler Collection, to be precise.

Comment: @Arafangion: you also stated, and I quote " gcc is a C compiler. g++ is a C++ compiler", while gcc can and will compile C++ programs.

Comment: @tom: sorry I missed the edit to the question - I'll delete my comment.

Comment: @whitelionV: As it happens you're right there - gcc can infact compile C++ programs (and can also link them, if you pass the right options), however, that's not how it's intended to be used today.  Do note that case is important when discussing GCC, especially if you come from a unix background. (Actually, I didn't know that it could properly compile C++ programs). It is still unrelated to the file extension.

Answer (score 1):

new is a reserved word in C++, change the variable name to something like new1. Or change the .cpp to c on your file name.